# Reference request for modules over polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules

We didn't cover these in class but have homework about them, but what do I call "$F[x]$-modules"? (how do I say it out loud) Modules over polynomial rings? What do I google to find lecture notes about these algebraic structures?

Sorry if this is a bit of a vague question, but I've never been in a situation where I don't know what to google. Also helpful would be good lecture notes on modules at the Dummit & Foote level.

Comment: See [$R$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)), where $R$ is a ring, e.g., $R=F[x]$ with a field $F$.  Try to google your title. I get lots of results, the first three even from this site.

Comment: I produce it as "F X modules," some people say "F of X module."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $F[X]$-module $V$ is exactly an $F$-module, i.e. a vector space over $F$, together with a linear transformation $V\to V$.

These are often studied as a special case of modules over principal ideal domains.  So, for example, there is a well-known [structure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) (note that $F[X]$ is mentioned explicitly in the corollaries section).